# Finding the Direction of Unboundedness

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

How do I find the Direction of Unboundedness for the problem below? I have looked everywhere to see an explanation and have not a found a step by step way to do so.

\begin{alignat}{4}
         \min \,& z = & \,    50 x_1 &     + & 100 x_2 &        &  &           \\
  \mbox{s.t.} &     &          7 x_1 &     + &   2 x_2 & \ge 28 &  & \tag{HIW} \\
                    &     &          2 x_1 &     + &  12 x_2 & \ge 24 &  & \tag{HIM} \\
                    &     & & & \llap{x_1,x_2} & \ge 0
\end{alignat}

Comment: Which constraints are active? Where is the starting point of the directions?

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189)
of your post. Pictures may not be legible,
cannot be searched and are not view-able to some,
such as those who use screen readers.
I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle.

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21400058 and https://orinanobworld.blogspot.com/2010/07/finding-extreme-rays-in-cplex.html

Comment: Is there a Direction of Unboundedness if the problem is not unbounded?